# Error while despalying microsoft report using report viewer

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report

I faced this error while using Microsoft report viewer when i publish it
but i didn't found in in local machine 
so my question 
 -- what this error refer to and how to fix it ??

```
An error has occurred during report processing.
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using the ReportViewer control within a .NET application or are you literally just viewing the report directly in the Report Manager in your browser?

Comment: I use report viewer control within a.net application

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the ProcessingMode property is set to Local or Remote depending on where the report will be hosted.  If you set it to Local, you need to set the LocalReport property, otherwise you need to use the ServerReport property when assigning the report to the control.